# append to end to line without newline

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, echo

When i try to append to the end of a file it creates a new line. Now I have tried to fix this with echo -n but that doenst work.

So what am I trying. I'm trying to get the following result:

```
Hello
This
Is
A
Test
```

But when I Append text with echo with

```
echo -n "Test2" >> file.txt
```

The following thing happens:

```
Hello
This
Is
A
Test
Test2
```

But what I want is:

```
Hello
This
Is
A
Test Test2
```

How am I able to do this? I have tried sed,echo and printf but none of these give the right result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '$s/$/ Test2/' file
```

or

```
truncate -s-1 file
echo -n " Test2" >> file
```

Output:

```
Hello
This
Is
A
Test Test2
```

Comment: Thank you, the sed option works, except it shows the output in the console. It doenst place it the text in the file. Is that normal?

Comment: If you want to edit your file "in place" with GNU sed add option `-i`: `sed -i '$s/$/ Test2/' file`

Comment: I have added ``sed -i '$s/$/ Test2/' tmp.txt``  but now I am ending up with an empty file

Comment: Do you use **GNU** sed?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what GNU is, (sorry still learning!) If you mean OS then I am using Centos 7.

Comment: you have an empty file because you probably did this at one point: `sed '...' tmp.txt > tmp.txt` -- if you do this, the shell will truncate the file *before* launching sed.

Comment: CentOS 7 uses GNU sed 4.2.2 (check `sed --version | head -n 1`). I've tested it with RHEL7 and GNU sed 4.2.2.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is working as I wanted it to work!